# TSQL Merging & Grouping Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have this sql result

```
color    red     AA
color    red     BB
color    red     CC
color    blue    DD
color    blue    EE
```

Is there way to merge by column, to obtain the following result?

```
color    red     AA
                 BB
                 CC
         blue    DD
                 EE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically something that you would do on the presentation layer of your application but if you want to do this in SQL, you could use `row_number()`:

```
select 
  case when col1rn = 1 then col1 else '' end col1,
  case when col2rn = 1 then col2 else '' end col2,
  col3
from
(
  select col1, col2, col3,
    row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1, col2, col3) col1rn,
    row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by col1, col2, col3) col2rn
  from yt
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02c5f/6).  You would replace the `from yt` with your query, giving the result:

```
|  COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
-----------------------
| color | blue |   DD |
|       |      |   EE |
|       |  red |   AA |
|       |      |   BB |
|       |      |   CC |
|  test | blue |   CC |
|       |  red |   AA |
|       |      |   BB |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using a ranking function to find your redundant data, and then a `case` can blank it out as necessary.  Note also that we're handling multiple "categories" or "groups" or whatever you happen to be partitioning by in your real data (shown as columns `a` and `b` here).

```
;with cte as (
    select 'color' as a, 'red' as b, 'AA' as c
    union all select 'color', 'red', 'BB'
    union all select 'color', 'red', 'CC'
    union all select 'color', 'blue', 'DD'
    union all select 'color', 'blue', 'EE'
    union all select 'smell', 'bad', 'AA'
    union all select 'smell', 'bad', 'BB'
    union all select 'smell', 'bad', 'CC'
    union all select 'smell', 'good', 'DD'
    union all select 'smell', 'good', 'EE'
)
select case when row_number() over (partition by a order by b, c) = 1 then a else '' end as ColA
    , case when row_number() over (partition by a, b order by c) = 1 then b else '' end as ColB
    , c as ColC
from cte
order by a, b, c
```

This will yield the following result:

```
ColA  ColB ColC
----- ---- ----
color blue DD
           EE
      red  AA
           BB
           CC
smell bad  AA
           BB
           CC
      good DD
           EE
```